# How to properly check for server error within Watin integration test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, watin

I am trying to detect if a server error was encountered during a watin test. I had thought the below code would do the trick however, in usage I am getting an NRE during test execution on this line: (Text.Contains("Server Error")).

Any suggestions on what to do here? A try catch block of some sort seems to not be the right thing to do here.

Thanks.

```
public class WatinBrowser : IE
{
    public WatinBrowser(string url, bool createInNewProcess) : base(url, createInNewProcess)
    {
    }

    public override void WaitForComplete(int waitForCompleteTimeOut)
    {
        base.WaitForComplete(waitForCompleteTimeOut);
        if (Text.Contains("Server Error"))
        {
            throw new ServerErrorException("A server error occured: " + Text);
        }
    }
}

public class ServerErrorException : Exception
{
    public ServerErrorException(string message): base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're overriding the version which takes a timeout parameter. This means it's possible control returns to your code without a document being loaded.

I recommend either:

1. Overriding the version of the method which doesn't take a timeout parameter
2. Adding a null check before calling the Contains method.

Code example for (2):

```
if(this.Text == null) throw new TimeoutException();

if(this.Text.Contains("Server Error"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up simply checking that text is not null.

Comment: As of WatiN 2.1.0 there is no version of `WaitForComplete` that takes no parameters.